# Verifier rejected class on API 16

Tags: android, verifyerror

I get following exception log if I try to open my app on **API 16** (on API 27 it is working):

```
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, referenced from method com.text.app.utilities.COLNotification.addPreAlarm
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 130: Landroid/app/AlarmManager;.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle (IJLandroid/app/PendingIntent;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AlarmManager.setExact, referenced from method com.text.app.utilities.COLNotification.addPreAlarm
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 129: Landroid/app/AlarmManager;.setExact (IJLandroid/app/PendingIntent;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0084
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.NotificationChannel.getSound, referenced from method com.text.app.utilities.COLNotification.buildNotification
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 264: Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;.getSound ()Landroid/net/Uri;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0131
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve exception class 435 (Landroid/os/FileUriExposedException;)
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x25e
W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/text/app/utilities/COLNotification;.buildNotification (Lcom/text/app/models/appModel;)V
W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x025e
W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/text/app/utilities/COLNotification;.buildNotification (Lcom/text/app/models/appModel;)V
W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/text/app/utilities/COLNotification;
```

All warnings are correct because the methods like "**NotificationChannel**" are not existing in API 16.
And the code I use for example the "NotificationChannel" is not executed because I check for the Build.VERSION.SDK.INT!

What exactly is the problem? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I used the "**FileUriException**" in a catch statement and this caused the the problem.

**Instead of:**

```
catch(FileUriException e) {
}
```

**I do now:**

```
catch(Exception e) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && e instanceof FileUriExposedException) {
    }
}
```